# looking for efficient way to group data on output in PHP

Tags: php, many-to-many, grouping

I have a table that holds products, another that holds variations and a third that hold product variations (many products can have many variations..both ways). I want to display (group by) each product and show the variations.

what i've read is just looping thru and comparing id's to see which record you are on, if a new one then adjust output...doesn't seem clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for a way to make a list of a single product and all it's variations. Or make a list of all products, and then for every product to show every variation of that product.

I'm assuming your tables look somewhat like this:

```
product
    productId
    description

variation
    variationId
    description

productVariation
    productVariationId
    productId
    variationId
```

For a single product and all it's variations you could use the following query, that does two inner joins.

```
SELECT
    P.description as product,
    V.description as variation
FROM
    product as P,
INNER JOIN
    productVariation AS PV
    ON PV.productId = P.productId
INNER JOIN
    variation as V
    ON V.variationId = PV.variationId
WHERE
    P.productId = 1
```

For the whole list of products, just omit the WHERE clause.
If a product has no variations, it won't be included in the list. If you want that, use LEFT JOINs instead.

The query will return the following

```
product variation
shoe    blue
shoe    green
shoe    red
hat     green
hat     purple
hat     yellow
sock    white
```

*Update:*

I'm guessing you want the data displayed as follows:

```
shoe
blue
green
red

hat
green
purple
yellow

sock
white
```

That can be done by the following PHP code.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        P.productId,
        P.description as product,
        V.description as variation
    FROM
        product as P,
    INNER JOIN
        productVariation AS PV
        ON PV.productId = P.productId
    INNER JOIN
        variation as V
        ON V.variationId = PV.variationId    
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

//first put all the results into an array so we can look backward and 
//see previous items
$resultSet = array();
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $resultSet[] = $record;
}

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($resultSet) ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $i == 0 ) {
        //for the first item, show the product name
        echo $resultSet[$i]['product'].'<br/>';
    } else if ($resultSet[$i]['productId'] != $resultSet[$i-1]['productId']) {
        //every time we encounter a new product
        //display a new line and show the product name
        echo '<br/>'.$resultSet[$i]['product'].'<br/>';
    }
    echo $resultSet[$i]['variation'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: that's is correct and I'm good on that side. it is the displaying of it on the page that doesn't seem so clean. I've done it by looping thru the query and comparing product id's to see if i'm on a new one, which feels dirty. 

How would you display this data if you wanted to show the product once and then all the variations? I'm sure its simple, but my code looks complicated for such an easy task.

Comment: So comparing productId's is actually the right way to do it, IMHO at least. If you show us your code you can point out what you think is dirty about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the SQL your choices are either one query where you do the comparisons or many queries which are dependent on the first.  On the other hand, ADOdb for PHP has ActiveRecords which can handle the one-to-many relationship for you.  http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm#onetomany

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying your SQL to show the data you want, that way there should be no need manually modify the data.  The [group by clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), or [order by clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) may be your friend here.

Comment: my sql does have the data, but it is reapeated due to the prouct having multiple variations. I'm just looking for a clean way to loop thru the results and group the results by product and then list the multiple variations, which the query has in the correct order (I am using order by, and can't use the group by which is for aggregation). I think this is a normal/simple thing, maybe too simple :).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a caching Sytem.

[image: No cache]

[image]

**Implementing The  Cache in PHP**

```
<?php
// start the output buffer
ob_start(); ?>

//Your usual PHP script and HTML here ...

<?php
$cachefile = "cache/home.html";
// open the cache file "cache/home.html" for writing
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
// save the contents of output buffer to the file
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
// close the file
fclose($fp);
// Send the output to the browser
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**Using the cached files**

```
<?php

$cachefile = "cache/home.html";

if (file_exists($cachefile)) {


    // the page has been cached from an earlier request

    // output the contents of the cache file

    include($cachefile); 


    // exit the script, so that the rest isnt executed
    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Wow...I can't see how this has any relevance to the question.